# How to define SQL function that collapses a table value to a scalar

Tags: sql, function

-- How do I define the function f below in SQL or T-SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE tableNames (tName varchar(100))

INSERT INTO tableNames VALUES ('someTableName')

SELECT * FROM f(tableNames)
```

Where I want to define f as follows:

```
f :: { {tName :: varchar(100)} } -> varchar(100)

f(tableNames) = 

if tableNames has no records, then return 'defaultTableName'

else if tableNames has more than one record, return 'duplicatesTableName'

else return the value of the tName attribute of the single tuple in tableNames.
```

Comment: sorry about the inconsistent formatting.

Comment: What DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...) are you using?

Comment: I am using  SQL Server 2016.

Comment: To clarify, I provided a definition for f just to make it more concrete. The part I am most interested in is the type conversion process from a relation of some similarity type to a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Check out how to create functions in SQL Server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). From what I understand of your situation, I would use the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f (@tName varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'defaultTableName'
                 WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'duplicateTableName'
                 ELSE MAX(tName)
            END) AS return_value
    FROM tableNames
)
```

Comment: I want to specify the table reference as the input argument, and have the attribute name specified in the body of the function as a literal. Right now it's the other way around.

So the type signature would be something like this:
CREATE FUNCTION f (@tableNames ?relation type specifier?)
RETURNS varchar(100)

Would you know how to modify your definition to accomplish that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `?relation type specifier?`. Are you looking for something like `f(@tableNames varchar(100)) RETURN SELECT ... FROM @tableNames`?

Comment: I mean something analogous to varchar(100), but indicating that the @tableNames argument is of a specific relation type, not a scalar type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for create a function in sql server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripWWWandCom (@input VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(250)

SET @Work = @Input

SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, 'www.', '')
SET @Work = REPLACE(@Work, '.com', '')

RETURN @work
END
```

it may help to you refer the below link

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/37db1d/creating-and-managing-user-defined-functions-in-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'defaultTableName'
             when count(*) > 1 then 'duplicatesTableName'
             else max(tName)
        end) as return_value
from tableNames;
```

This is easy to incorporate into a function, although I don't see the need for that.  You can just as easily make it a view.